# Index outside bounds of array

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm trying to get all data from facebook

But I get an error

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Code:

```
 public void Comments(string cmtid)
    {
        var accessToken = "***********";
        var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        clientfeed = client.Get(cmtid).ToString();

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(clientfeed);

        JArray datas = (JArray)obj["data"];

        for (int i = 0; i < datas.Count; i++)
        {
            if (obj["data"][i]["message"] != null)
            {
                strPostComment = obj["data"][i]["message"].ToString();
                if (strPostComment.Contains("'"))
                {
                    strPostComment = strPostComment.Replace("'", "''");
                }
                strPostCommentId = obj["data"][i]["id"].ToString();
                strPostCommentNameId = obj["data"][i]["from"]["id"].ToString();
                strPostCommentName = obj["data"][i]["from"]["name"].ToString();
                splitCommentId = strPostCommentId.Split('_');
                strPostCommentdate = obj["data"][i]["created_time"].ToString();
                if (strPostCommentdate.Contains("T"))
                {
                    strPostCommentdate = strPostCommentdate.Replace("T", " ");
                }
                abccommenttime = strPostCommentdate.Substring(0, strPostCommentdate.ToString().Length - 5);

                if (strPostCommentName == "IIPL BANK")
                {
                    IIPLCustomer(strPostCommentNameId, abccommenttime);
                }
                else
                {
                    Customer(strPostCommentNameId);
                }

                if (datas.Count != 0)
                {
                    DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
                    OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = DbReader[0].ToString();
                        cnt = Convert.ToInt32(count);

                        if ((cnt == 0) && (strPostComment != ""))
                        {
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("insert into mw_response(post_id,response,response_id, resp_date,community) values('" + splitCommentId[1] + "','" + strPostComment + "','" + splitCommentId[2] + "', to_date('" + abccommenttime + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),'" + fb_community + "')", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            //update productid and customerid
                            DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("update mw_response set prod_id = (select prod_id from mw_post where post_id='" + splitCommentId[1] + "'),customer_id = (select customer_id from mw_customer where customer_id = '" + strPostCommentNameId + "') where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
                            DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (strPostCommentName != "IIPL BANK")
                            {
                                //calling comment web service
                                createComment(splitCommentId[2]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    DbReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is what the code terminated by Indes was outside the bounds of the array

```
  if (datas.Count != 0)
  {
     DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
     OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you check the size of splitCommentId[] before using it?

Comment: `if (datas.Count != 0)` is meaning less. as it wont enter the loop `for (int i = 0; i < datas.Count; i++)` if count is less than 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access data at index **2** in **splitCommentId** without checking if data at that actually exists here:

```
DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
```

you could do it by this way

```
if (datas.Count != 0 && splitCommentId.length >= 3)
{
     DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
     OleDbDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the below line

```
splitCommentId = strPostCommentId.Split('_');
```

check what is the length of splitCommentId. It will be 2. Which means that in below line

```
DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[2] + "'", DbConnection);
```

**splitCommentId[2]** will not be present. Hence the error. If you want to access the second element, then do it like this

```
DbCommand = new OleDbCommand("select count(response_id) from mw_response where response_id = '" + splitCommentId[1] + "'", DbConnection);
```

Your code **createComment(splitCommentId[2]);** will also throw exception.